# Возможно ли в SELECT выбрать всe колонки но исключить одну или две без явного указания необходимых колонок?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Возможно ли, в PL/SQL, выбрать все колонки, но исключить одну или две без явного указания необходимых колонок?

Например, есть такие поля в таблице сотрудников:

```sql
create table employee (
    id number,
    firstname varchar (32),
    lastname varchar (64),
    hobbies varchar (4000)
);
```

Возможно ли написать такой запрос:

```
select * from employee
```

, но исключить колонку `hobbies`, чтобы не писать такое:

```
select id, firstname, lastname from employee
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/9133120/6571020

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 12c возможно объявить колонки невидимыми - [*invisible columns*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#GUID-D7E99BBA-192C-41E7-9150-62AA188725E4).

После изменения таблицы из вопроса, колонка `hobbies` будет исключена из выборки:

```sql
alter table employee modify hobbies invisible;

select * from employee;
```

Вывод:

```
        ID FIRSTNAME                        LASTNAME                             
---------- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
         1 aaa                              bbb
```

Возможно более удачным решением будет - вместо изменения структуры таблицы создать для неё [представление](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#BABBDHGD):

```sql
create or replace view viewEmployee (id, firstname, lastname, hobbies invisible) as 
select * from employee
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы исключить из выборки определённые колонки можно создать полиморфную табличную функцию ([PFT - polymorphic table function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-981102A8-5204-4931-B10A-93486304B184) 18c+).

Очевидным преимуществом по сравнению с другими решениями - PFT не зависит от источника данных, например, определённой таблицы. Другими словами, одна и та же функция может быть применима к любым источникам данных с совершенно различными структурами. Источником данных может быть: таблица, представление, CTE, а также другая табличная функция.

```sql
insert into employee values (1, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'hobby1, hobby2');

create table person as
select 2 id, 'ccc' fname, 'ddd' lname, date'1999-01-01' birthday from dual;

select * from tabfuncpkg.filterCols (employee, columns (hobbies))
union all
select * from tabfuncpkg.filterCols (person, columns (birthday))
;
with t (id, name1, name2, description, price) as (
    select 3 id, 'eee', 'fff', 'desc', 12.34 from dual
)
select * from tabfuncpkg.filterCols (t, columns (description, price));
```

Вывод:

```
        ID FIRSTNAME                        LASTNAME                                                        
---------- -------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 aaa                              bbb                                                             
         2 ccc                              ddd    

        ID NAM NAM
---------- --- ---
         3 eee fff
```

Реализация функции:

```sql
create or replace package tabfuncpkg as
    function filterCols (tab table, cols columns) return table pipelined row polymorphic using tabfuncpkg;
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t, cols dbms_tf.columns_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t;
end tabfuncpkg; 
/
create or replace package body tabfuncpkg as
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t, cols dbms_tf.columns_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t as 
    begin 
        for ix in 1..tab.column.count () loop
            for jx in 1..cols.count () loop  
                tab.column (ix).pass_through := tab.column (ix).description.name != cols (jx);
                exit when not tab.column(ix).pass_through;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return null;
    end;
end tabfuncpkg;
/
```

Обратите внимание, сама функция `filterCols` ни имеет никакой логики. Функция `describe` используется только на этапе компиляции, а при выполнении запроса больше не участвует и не вызывается. То есть, исходя из источника входных данных на этапе компиляции будет сгенерирована структура источника выходных данных.